C++ standard (non-)phrasing about non odr-use of *this in compound-statement of a lambda-expression
I am a bit confused by a sentence in the standard (I am watching draft n4849 for C++20, §7.5.5.2 - 11, i.e., [expr.prim.lambda.capture.6], or also https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.prim.lambda.capture), about what id-expression refers from the compound statement of a lambda expression.
It reads:

Every id-expression within the compound-statement of a lambda-expression that is an odr-use of an entity captured by copy is transformed into an access to the corresponding unnamed data member of the closure type.


[Note: An id-expression that is not an odr-use refers to the original entity, never to a member of the closure type. However, such an id-expression can still cause the implicit capture of the entity. — end note]


If *this is captured by copy, each expression that odr-uses *this is transformed to instead refer to the corresponding unnamed data member of the closure type.

My question is: why "instead" in last paragraph ?
I have the feeling (uniquely in terms of grammar) that in last paragraph the part 'that odr-uses' should be removed, as this would provide a sense for "instead", compared to the general case where the access to the data member happens only in case of odr-use (1st paragraph), otherwise the original entity is referred (2nd paragraph).
Or, another interpretation is that "instead" is for the more general term 'expression' compared to 'id-expression' but in this case my question switches into "what the standard requires about non-odr-use of *this ?"

"instead" here means "instead of refering to *this", in other words, "instead of refering to the object that this points to".

Thank you Igor Tandetnik,  this makes sense.
Any comment about non odr-use ? Should I assume it refers to the original object as any other captured entity ?
I would have liked to see something like "This applies also to *this" after the first paragraph, so that such doubts would not be triggered.

For non-odr use, it likely doesn't make a difference anyway. It's things like sizeof(*this) or decltype(*this). The non-normative note is likely there just to remind about implicit capture. But*this is never captured implicitly, so the issue is moot there.

ok to me, Igor. The point of view you expressed makes sense. Still believe the wording may be improved, but ok, thanks.
